# Are there any good XmlMembershipProvider and XmlRoleProvider implementations out there that can be used for Commercial purposes?

Tags: asp.net, roleprovider, asp.net-membership

Does anyone know of any good XmlMembershipProvider and XmlRoleProvider classes that are able to be used for commercial purposes, royalty free?

I know that BlogEngine.NET uses an XmlMembershipProvider and XmlRoleProvider, but it's covered under the Microsoft Recipricol License which states that you have to provide your users/customers the source code to any file that contains source code from any file that was previously licensed under the Microsoft Recipricol License and that new file is now under that same license. It's a bit viral, so I'm incidentally can't use it within a commercial project I'm working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a real simple implementation of one:

http://madskristensen.net/post/XML-membership-provider-for-ASPNET-20.aspx

Answer (score 1):

there is another version of that same class that have some issues fixed 
http://www.sourceinaction.com/blog/asp.net-xml-membership-provider